# Cast error by printing the elements of a string in a pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, casting

First: I'm a beginner with pointers.

I just want to print the chars of the strings in the pointer Array. It works fine, but I get two Problems in Eclipse Juno (Mac OS X):

1. assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

2. format '%c' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *'

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *words[] = {"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5"};
    char *tempWord,*tempChar;
    int i, j, numElems2;

    int numElems = sizeof words / sizeof words[0];
    for(i = 0; i < numElems; ++i)
    {
        tempWord = words[i];
        numElems2 = strlen(tempWord);

        for(j = 0; j < numElems2; ++j)
        {
            tempChar = tempWord[j];
            printf("%c", tempChar);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand the first problem, but don't know how to solve it. The second problem I don't understand. What has a 'char' to do with 'int'?

Maybe there is somebody who can give me some advice.
Thanks.

Comment: In addition to the answers given here I would like to recommend the clang C compiler which gives very clear error messages.

Answer (score 4):

`tempChar` needs to be a `char`, not a `char *` as you currently have it.

Both of your warning messages tell you this.

Comment: Oh boy, so easy to solve, thanks :-)

Comment: To avoid confusion it is also a good idea to put the declaration of tempChar on its own line (`char tempChar;`).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, what this code should to do, but, firstly tempChar must be type char not *char, if you want to print string with printf, you need to use "%s"...